# Greenplum: Functions that execute SQL statements from the segDBs are not yet supported

Tags: sql, postgresql, greenplum

I get this error when I try to call a function from an Insert Trigger set on one of my tables in the SNE GP Edition:

```
ERROR:  Functions that execute SQL statements from the segDBs are not yet supported (spi.c:203)  (seg0 localhost:50001 pid=5504)
DETAIL:  
  SQL statement "SELECT DISTINCT min(zasn) FROM zeusasn WHERE zasn IN (SELECT asn FROM asntable where ip >>= '10.29.249.121')"
PL/pgSQL function "eptriggerfn" line 5 at SQL statement

********** Error **********

ERROR: Functions that execute SQL statements from the segDBs are not yet supported (spi.c:203)  (seg0 localhost:50001 pid=5504)
SQL state: XX000
Detail: 
  SQL statement "SELECT DISTINCT min(zasn) FROM zeusasn WHERE zasn IN (SELECT asn FROM asntable where ip >>= '10.29.249.121')"
PL/pgSQL function "eptriggerfn" line 5 at SQL statement
```

What can be the cause of this? Triggers + functions are working perfectly fine with another table in the same DB.

Thanks in advance!

Rgds,
Kiran

Answer (score 3):

Because Greenplum does distributed processing across multiple nodes, a query within a query cannot utilise the full processing capability, so it is not supported.

When we made the switch we had a similar problem:

```
select      *,
            country_name(country_id)
from        sales
where       country_id in (224, 105);
```

The function `country_name()` basically did a sub query for each id to get the country name. So we had to change the query to:

```
select      *,
            c.country_name
from        sales
left join   country as c using (country_id)
where       country_id in (224, 105);
```

... and the problem was solved. I know it seems like a lot of work, but the benefits are worth it.